# is ‘fine’ in the sense ‘of very good quality’ gradable?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparatives, superlative-degree, degree-of-comparison

**Fine** in the sense *of very good quality* seems to be an absolute adjective, and since absolute adjectives are not gradable, so I am wondering if this principle applies to **fine** in the sense ‘of very good quality’ as well?

Regarding why **fine** seems an absolute adjective to me, let us take a moment to consider the following etymology of *fine* from the Oxford Dictionary of English and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fine):

> from old French *fin* ‘end’, cognate with Eng. *finish*

This etymology brings me the impression that it means ‘too good to be improved further’ or ‘so good as cannot be better’, so I feel like **fine** is much like an ‘absolute adjective’ such as *superior*.

Comment: This question is entirely answerable with a dictionary (specifically, learner's dictionaries tend to specifically cover this [example](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fine_1)). Unfortunately this means this question is off topic.

Comment: The notion that absolute adjectives are inherently non-gradable is, at best, a very prescriptivist way of looking at it.  Even "perfect" is gradable, though [less than it used to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+perfect).

Comment: @Laurel Not necessarily. Our [research guidelines](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11824/124936) would allow this question to stay open if a [proper citation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for the quotation can be added. Some reasons that may make it more acceptable is that it raises the bar of evidence, and/or shows that the information is at least somewhat hard to find, which is not to mention the etymology is interesting. Would you please inform us which which source you checked for the etymology Lynno? I can't find it myself, but it seems to be valid info.

Comment: @Tonepoet thanks for your advice, the etym. info is from OED and wiktionary, which i just instert in the post.

Comment: "This is a fine wine, but that other blend is even finer."

Comment: It should be noted that "fine" is often used as one step in a "grading scale".  The [Sheldon coin grading scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_coin_grading_scale), for instance, grades coins through poor, fair, good, very good, *fine*, very fine, and uncirculated (with a few more qualifiers thrown in to produce in-between grades).

Answer (score 4):

*Fine* is as gradable an adjective as was ever spoken. *Finer* and *finest* are used half a dozen times each in Shakespeare. They're in common figures of speech: *the finer things*, *their finest hour*.

So then, why doesn't the etymological argument hold up?

First, the past is not the present. If *fine* really did mean "too good to be improved further", then it would mean "perfect"; and yes, there would be less occasion to use it comparatively or superlatively. But that's not what it means.

Second, even absolute adjectives like *perfect* or *complete* are usually gradable. *More perfect* is understood to mean more nearly perfect, and *more complete* means more nearly complete, or more thorough.

Comment: "Fine" is also used in speech to indicate reluctant acceptance of the inevitable as in "There's no one else to empty the bedpans so you'll have to spend your 16 hour shift doing it, alright?" "Fine". Obviously it's not perfect but I'm going to have to do it whatever I say.